# POO: Como modelo registros/entities asociados a otros entities?

Tags: php

Estoy creando un proyecto php con /models (clases de entidad), /DAO (sobre el que utilizo éste patron para acceso bd), /controllers, /services, etc.

Como es un proyecto educativo, utilizando un enfoque tradicional de OOP, me encuentro en el común problema de *¿Como mapeo lectura/escritura de mi modelo de dominio?* Pero yendo a mi pregunta: Si tuviera por ejemplo una oficina de abogados, sobre el que c/u de éstos está cargado, y tienen su registro de casos (issues) de cada cliente.
Si dijera: Es una clase *pertenece a* -> cliente, abogado. Puedo hacer composición:

```
class Issue {
  // Instancia del abogado
  protected $lawyer;
  // Instancia del cliente
  protected $customer;

  protected $id;
  protected $title; //etc...

  // getters y setters...
}
```

El problema con ésto, viene cuando quiero almacenar. No voy a almacenar Issue con esos dos otros objetos que contiene, porque se supone tienen un *lifetime* distinto, no es la clase dueña del resto, y hay una api propia para guardar c/u éstos. O podría ser excepcionalmente que al guardar sean solo los datos propios y no los componentes?

Una alternativa a ésto, y explicado en [éste](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212902/oop-objects-nested-objects-and-daos) thread, es: entities mantenerlas simples, sin composiciones y solo datos, como mucho, referenciales a la asociacion. Y entonces para unir una clase accesoria:

```
class IssueReport {
  // Instancia del abogado
  protected $lawyer;
  // Instancia del cliente
  protected $customer;
  // Instancia del caso (una clase sin composiciones)
  protected $issue;

  // getters y setters...
}
```

Con lo que creo estaría haciendo una forma de asociación muy válida.

Dicho esto, que enfoque, (u otro), sería mas saludable para estos casos, en que manejo practicamente SQL para almacenar mis clases?